# Kafka - completed rollback due to timeout

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using Kafka where we faced an issue, one of the consumer stopped processing any message but the broker did not get notified of this somehow and it didn't rebalance it as well.

So there was a huge lag in that partition.

In the broker logs I see below

> Completed rollback ongoing transaction of transactionid:  due to timeout (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)

Why it did not get notification and triggered rebalancing
Confluent version - 5.1.0-2.11
Kafka version 2.11

Comment: What you write is a description of what happened. But what is your question?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: What does "stopped processing" exactly mean -- did the JVM crash? As long as the consumer send heartbeats, no rebalance would be triggered.

Comment: Streaming stopped it didnt pick up any message from a certain point, can you please help with with the log i mentioned, what does it mean? Is it a failure scenario?

Comment: Seems Kafka Streams started a new transaction but never completed it -- by default, commit.interval is `100ms` and the transaction timeout is `60seconds`.

Comment: Is it an issue, if no which property should I look for, to resolve such issues

Comment: Will such issue not cause rebalance to trigger?